# Android:How to type floating point value while typing to EditText

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface

I am new to android and trying to develop simple UI based app. I want the  EditText which the user will enter the amount as a floating-point value (e.g., “1000.00”).

Any help and reference will be of great help.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this functionality in two ways. first is to statically set the attribute `inputType` in your layout.xml file or secondly you can dynamically apply method `setInputType` on edittext from activity.java. Below are the code snippets for both

**Method 1**

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    <!-- Add following attribute to your edittext in xml -->
    android:inputType="numberDecimal" >
</EditText>
```

**Method 2**

```
//Add following line in your .java file after instantiating the edittext text1
text1.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
android:inputType="numberDecimal"
```

This ensures the user can only enter a number.

More detail can be found here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/text.html

And further details here: [http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:inputType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3ainputType)

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use the EditText attribute android:digits="0123456789." This will make it so they would only be able to use those as entries.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `Float Number` on your EditText  then add  `android:inputType="numberDecimal"`

in your `Edittext` tag in xml,i.e.

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal" />
```

Or you can also set it programmatically as

```
editText1.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set an `inputType` in your `EditText`

```
  <EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"/>
```